# How to identify plurals of noun

Tags: java, inflector

I've seen people asked similar questions but without any good answer. I now encountered the same question, can anyone help?

See below:

Input: a list of words

Output: identify nouns in their plural forms, convert them into their singular forms if possible

Comment: What are you looking for - a library? code? - and [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I tried java inflector, but it can only convert singular to plural. i am using wordnet to detect nouns, but it cant detect all the singular nouns. i think maybe i missed some info, so i post my question here. researched already too.

Comment: detect nouns in plural form within a list of words or say from a sentence.

Answer (score 2):

WordNet will be able to help with stripping plurals. It is a full morphological dictionary of English language.

http://wordnet.princeton.edu/

The JAWS is a simple Java API which talks to WordNet, though others exist.

http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/index.html

Note, WordNet will not perfectly deal with the various idiosyncrasies of English, from [their FAQ](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/frequently-asked-questions/other/):

> Along with a set of irregular forms (e.g. children - child), it uses a
>   sequence of simple rules, stripping common English endings until it
>   finds a word form present in WordNet. Furthermore, it assumes its
>   input is a valid inflected form. So, it will take "childes" to
>   "child", even though "childes" is not a word.

Comment: Ina, thanks. I am actually using wordnet. The thing is i think wordnet does very limited plural thing and they stated this very clearly on their wiki. In other words, I dont think wordnet can solve this. Let me know if i miss anything.

Comment: Just give you an example, for word "knives", WordNet failed to detect it as noun.

Comment: True, WordNet will fail on some examples but should cover a large proportion of your inputs. If you have a fairly standard set of inputs, you could special-case those which still fail.